# postgres regex substring escape character

Tags: regex, postgresql

The data contains a series of names of the format:

`ABC123456
XYZ987654
DE-234567`

The query

```
select distinct(substring(field, '([A-Z]{1,3})')) pref, count(*) tot from table;
```

identifies entries with characters.
The question is: what is the escape character pull the '-' character along with the alpha characters. The '-' character is used in the select character sequence [A-Z]. How can that selection sequence be extended to include the '-' character.

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The '-' character is used in the select character sequence [A-Z]

Dash `-` is interpreted as a range only when it is in the middle of other characters. If you put it at the beginning or at the end of a character class, it becomes just a regular character:

```
select distinct(substring(field, '([A-Z-]{1,3})')) pref, count(*) tot from  table;
--                                     ^
```

`[-A-Z]` would work as well.